How to connect to another wireguard server from a wireguard server
I have a VPS with open ports, and a PC behind a NAT, meaning the PC cannot accept incoming connections. I need to use internet through my PC.
So I am thinking my pc and my phone both will connect to the VPS wg server, and then all of them will surf the internet through my PC.
Now I have set up a wireguard server on the VPS, which everyone can connect to. I have also created a wg server on my PC, and it forwards everything to the internet. Now I need to connect this PC wg server to the VPS server. I have been searching for a long time, but could not find anything on how to connect to a wg server (VPS) from another wg server (PC). Both the servers are just listening, I want my pc server to reach out to the VPS and make the connection.
